# Performance issue while storing fields in documents stand-alone vs inside of an object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have fields like:

```
"ValueA": "KeyA",
"ValueB": "KeyB",
"ValueC": "KeyC",
"ValueD": "KeyD"
```

If I store them into an object instead of stand-alone fields in my MongoDB collection like:

```
"FormFields": {
 "ValueA": "KeyA",
 "ValueB": "KeyB",
 "ValueC": "KeyC",
 "ValueD": "KeyD"
}
```

When the number of documents reaches hundreds of thousands or millions in the collection, how does the query I use to fetch these fields from the object perform compared to the query I would normally fetch the data as a stand-alone field? Is there a serious performance difference?

The reason I want to store them inside of an object is field names can be dynamically changed according to input given by users. By this way, I am aiming to fetch object directly so that I am going to know all the fields I need are there since a document in the collection has >50 fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant overhead for either structure from a performance POV when using a naive query.

But when querying large scale you'd want index whatever you're trying to query. In both scenarios your best bet is to create a [wildcard index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-wildcard/) - In this case the second structure would be the better option as you could control better which fields to include in that index.